# Docker compose: Wordpress with Nginx/LetsEncrypt Proxy 502

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose

my Docker compose file looks as follows:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  nginx-web:
    image: nginx
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    container_name: ${NGINX_WEB:-nginx-web}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${IP:-0.0.0.0}:${DOCKER_HTTP:-80}:80"
      - "${IP:-0.0.0.0}:${DOCKER_HTTPS:-443}:443"
    volumes:
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd:ro
    logging:
      driver: ${NGINX_WEB_LOG_DRIVER:-json-file}
      options:
        max-size: ${NGINX_WEB_LOG_MAX_SIZE:-4m}
        max-file: ${NGINX_WEB_LOG_MAX_FILE:-10}

  nginx-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup ${NGINX_WEB:-nginx-web} -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    container_name: ${DOCKER_GEN:-nginx-gen}
    restart: always
    environment:
      SSL_POLICY: ${SSL_POLICY:-Mozilla-Intermediate}
    volumes:
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/htpasswd:/etc/nginx/htpasswd:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro
    logging:
      driver: ${NGINX_GEN_LOG_DRIVER:-json-file}
      options:
        max-size: ${NGINX_GEN_LOG_MAX_SIZE:-2m}
        max-file: ${NGINX_GEN_LOG_MAX_FILE:-10}

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: ${LETS_ENCRYPT:-nginx-letsencrypt}
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: ${DOCKER_GEN:-nginx-gen}
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: ${NGINX_WEB:-nginx-web}
    logging:
      driver: ${NGINX_LETSENCRYPT_LOG_DRIVER:-json-file}
      options:
        max-size: ${NGINX_LETSENCRYPT_LOG_MAX_SIZE:-2m}
        max-file: ${NGINX_LETSENCRYPT_LOG_MAX_FILE:-10}

  database:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 7ctDGg5YUwkCPkCW
    entrypoint:
      sh -c "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
    volumes:
      - ./data/database/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend-network

  auth:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: auth
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: mariadb
      DB_ADDR: database
      DB_DATABASE: users
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: jk2zKvGkJXBsrNMV
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: M+f{7_Hc>&Z.;6W6
      JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=false"
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/certs/pm-app.de/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt
      - ./data/webproxy/nginx-data/certs/pm-app.de/key.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backend-network

#  fileupload:
#    image: openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
#    container_name: fileupload
#    ports:
#      - 8082:8082
#    depends_on:
#      - database
#      - auth
#    volumes:
#      - ./fileupload-server.jar:/fileupload-server.jar
#    command: ["java", "-jar", "fileupload-server.jar"]
#    networks:
#      - backend-network

#  websocket:
#    image: openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
#    container_name: websocket
#    ports:
#      - 8083:8083
#    depends_on:
#      - database
#      - auth
#    volumes:
#      - ./websocket-server.jar:/websocket-server.jar
#    command: ["java", "-jar", "websocket-server.jar"]
#    networks:
#      - backend-network

#  resource:
#    image: openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
#    container_name: resource
#    ports:
#      - 8081:8081
#    depends_on:
#      - fileupload
#      - websocket
#      - auth
#    volumes:
#      - ./backend/resource-server.jar:/resource-server.jar
#    command: ["java", "-jar", "resource-server.jar"]
#    networks:
#      - backend-network

#  frontend:
#    image: nginx:alpine
#    container_name: frontend
#    ports:
#      - 4200:4200
#    depends_on:
#      - resource
#    volumes:
#      - ./frontend/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
#      - ./frontend/dist/propositum-frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
#    networks:
#      - frontend-network

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: QKJFUfZbv7jMB5ba
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_
      VIRTUAL_HOST: domain.de
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: domain.de
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: info@domain.de
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
    - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - webproxy

  ftp:
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:hardened-latest
    container_name: ftp
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: Ip
      FTP_USER_NAME: "ftp"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "+/x~qy//vf(S6L:<"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/var/www/html"
      FTP_USER_UID: 33
      FTP_USER_GID: 33
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      #- ./data/ftp:/etc/ssl/private
    ports:
      - 21:21
      - 30000:30000

volumes:
  database_data:
  wordpress_data:

networks:
  backend-network:
  frontend-network:
  webproxy:
    external:
      name: "webproxy"
```

But when I try to access the wordpress instance over the browser, to start the installation process. And only got an 502 bad gateway.

The interesting thing is that it already worked before, the only thing what I've changed was, that I am moved all config files and directories, which was before in a seperate folder, to the datadata folder (./data/webproxy) and cut out the services from the old docker compose file to an existing one and also edited file paths from the mapped volumes. Hopefully this are enough details to help me, otherwise let me know when you need more information.

So far,
Daniel

Comment: It probably has to do with the Nginx `default.conf` file. Check the `root` directory directive.